# Property 'reset' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import, graphql

I came across a SO overflow which suggested that we can use `e.target.reset()`on forms to reset forms after submitting. However, I am unable to use it in my case:

```
export default function RemoveUserPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved, setIsRemoved] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [removeUser] = useMutation<DeleteUserReponse>(REMOVE_USER);

  let submitForm = (email: string) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    removeUser({
      variables: {
        email: email,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<DeleteUserReponse>) => {
        setIsRemoved(true);
      }})
  };
  const initialSTATE={ email: '' }

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        //initialValues={{ email: '' }}
        initialValues={{ ...initialSTATE}}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}>
        {props => {
          const {
            values: { email },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched,
          } = props;
          const change = (name: string, e: FormEvent) => {
            e.persist();
            handleChange(e);
            setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
          };
          return (
            <div className="main-content">
              <form
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  submitForm(email);
                  e.target.reset();
                }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ''}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <CustomButton
                    disabled={!isValid || !email}
                    text={'Remove User'}
                  />
                </div>
              </form>
              <br></br>
              {isSubmitted && StatusMessage(isRemoved, errorMessage)}
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I use it at the end of my `onSubmit`, I get the error mentioned above. How can I fix this?

Comment: try to use this.reset()

Comment: @Prince ```'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, since I know that the e.target is a form element I just set it's type like so:

```
const target = e.target as HTMLFormElement
target.reset()
```

It works. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

> I came across a SO overflow which suggested that we can use `e.target.reset()` on forms to reset forms after submitting.

Could be valid before react era. Nowadays react updates real DOM on props changes.

**Want to reset form? Render it using new values!**

Based on [docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#handlesubmit-e-reactformeventhtmlformevent--void) you should pass `handleSubmit` prop to rendered `<form/>`:

```
<form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
```

This `handleSubmit` will call (after validation) Formik's `onSubmit` handler. **This is a place where you should define custom logic**.

`onSubmit` is called with `(values, actions)` so you can

```
submitForm(values.email);
actions.resetForm()
```

or pass `actions` to your `submitForm` and use `resetForm` in this method.